# Fix screen orientation to landscape or portrait in mobile web app

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am building a mobile website where certain pages should open only in landscape or portrait. I have tried to do it using jquery by using condition

```
if(width<height) {
    $('body').addClass('landscape');
}
```

In landscape CSS I am rotating the screen using CSS transform.

Is this method good or is there a better way of doing this.

Comment: certainly you need to add a parent class or id,and then give style in media queries to achieve your goal.

Comment: I can't use media queries as this is a hybrid app and has to work in all devices. I have used fluid css throughout the mobile based site for that reason.